# loop snapshotdata and for each for markers Flutter

Tags: loops, flutter, widget, openstreetmap, markers

I have a question: I'm trying **to fetch** markers from an existing API, but I don't want to manually write the longitude and latitude of all 3000 thousand points, so I created a method **forEach** that must iterate through all the points. But I got the following error:

```
The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (Stops) => Null)
```

Also I tried to use a **loop for...if** and start a loop inside the **snapshot** but it didn't work because it can return  only the widget, so when I return the flutter map and then try to induce latitude and longitude, nothing works.

**UPDATE**

Thank to Sam Chan for his answer but after I tried both answers it gives me an error:

`The method 'map' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: map<Marker>(Closure: (Stops) => Marker)`

I don't get it what am I doing wrong?

Also I have an id's for each markers and if i wrote this:

```
final List<Stops> listStops = stopsFromJson(response.body);
    for (var i = 1; i < listStops.length; i++) {
      if (listStops[i].stId != null) {
        return Stops.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[1]);
      } else {
        return Stops();
      }

And after that I wrote here this: 

MarkerLayerOptions(
                      markers:[
                        Marker(
                          point: latLng.LatLng(snapshot.data.stLong, snapshot.data.stLat),
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          builder: (ctx) => Icon(Icons.add)
```

As a result, only one marker appears on the map, to which ID = 1 belongs. I understand that I have to use a list, but when I use a list, nothing works.

my code

```
List<Stops> listStops;
  Future<List<Stops>> futureStops;
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureStops = fetchStops();
  }
```

```
 body: FutureBuilder<List<Stops>>(
            future: futureStops,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                listStops.forEach((Stops) {
                  allMarkers = listStops.map(
                    (Stops) => Marker(
                        point: latLng.LatLng(Stops.stLong, Stops.stLat),
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                        builder: (_) => Icon(
                              Icons.person_pin,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            )),
                  );
                });
                return FlutterMap(
                  options: MapOptions(
                    center: latLng.LatLng(48.707103, 44.516939),
                    zoom: 13.0,
                  ),
                  layers: [
                    new TileLayerOptions(
                        urlTemplate:
                            "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    MarkerLayerOptions(
                      markers: allMarkers,
                    )
                  ],
```

Here I want to call markers with latitude and longitude, but nothing works. I also tried to write a loop inside my model, but nothing worked there either. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
MarkerLayerOptions( markers: allMarkers,
```

**Can you give me a hint?**

**thank you all guys!**

also my model

```
Future <List<Stops>> fetchStops () async {
//here is  my link
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<Stops> listStops = stopsFromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[1]);
      return listStops;
      } else {
    return List<Stops>();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop in `snapshot.data`

like

```
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      snapshot.data.forEach((Stops) {
                      allMarkers = listStops.map(
                        (Stops) => Marker(
                            point: latLng.LatLng(Stops.stLong, Stops.stLat),
              ...
```

Or

```
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      listStops=snapshot.data;
                      listStops.forEach((Stops) {
                      allMarkers = listStops.map(
                        (Stops) => Marker(
                            point: latLng.LatLng(Stops.stLong, Stops.stLat),
              ...
```

I hope it solve your issue.

Comment: i tried both of your answers @SamChan and the second one gives me an error : ``` The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Marker>(Closure: (Stops) => Marker)
```